# Shuffling sections of an ordered list based on tuple values

Tags: python, algorithm, shuffle

I have a list as follows and I  want to shuffle the elements that have the same frequency while keeping the elements with different frequencies in the correct positions. The code below works; however, it is not that nice. I was wondering if anyone had some suggestions e.g. using list comprehension.

```
pieces_needed = [('a',1),('b',1),('d',1),('c',2),('g',3),('f',5),('z',5)]
temp = []
new_pieces_needed = []
current_freq = 1
for i in pieces_needed:
   if i[1] == current_freq:
      temp.append(i)
   else:
      random.shuffle(temp)
      new_pieces_needed +=  temp
      temp = []
      temp.append(i)
      current_freq = i[1]

random.shuffle(temp)       
new_pieces_needed +=  temp

print(new_pieces_needed)
```

Example output:

```
[('d',1),('b',1),('a',1),('c',2),('g',3),('z',5),('f',5)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Both branches of the `if` statement have the line:

   ```
   temp.append(i)
   ```

   This duplication could be avoided.
2. The variable `temp` could have a better name, for example `group` or `current_group`.
3. `i[1]` is evaluated twice.
4. The variable name `i` is normally used for an *index*, but in this case it is an element of the list, so it could have a better name.
5. These lines appear twice:

   ```
   random.shuffle(temp)
   new_pieces_needed +=  temp
   ```

   This duplication could be avoided by postponing the shuffles until the groups have been found, like this:

   ```
   # Group pieces_needed according to their frequency.
   groups = []
   current_freq = object()
   for piece in pieces_needed:
       freq = piece[1]
       if freq != current_freq:
           groups.append([])
           current_freq = freq
       groups[-1].append(piece)

   # Randomly shuffle each group.
   for group in groups:
       random.shuffle(group)

   # Concatenate the shuffled groups.
   new_pieces_needed = [piece for group in groups for piece in group]
   ```
6. There is something arbitrary about the use of "pieces" and "frequency" and `piece[1]`. The same general algorithm would work for any kind of data, not just pieces. So I think the code would be clearer if we generalized it like this, taking an arbitrary iterable and an optional key function:

   ```
   def shuffle_groups(iterable, key=None):
       """Group the iterable (using the key function if supplied), randomly
       shuffle each group, and return the concatenation of the shuffled
       groups.

       """
   ```

   and then we can shuffle the pieces by passing [`operator.itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for the `key` argument:

   ```
   from operator import itemgetter
   new_pieces_needed = shuffle_groups(pieces_needed, key=itemgetter(1))
   ```
7. The grouping logic can be delegated to [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and the concatenation to [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

   ```
   from itertools import chain, groupby
   from random import shuffle

   def shuffle_groups(iterable, key=None):
       """Group the iterable (using the key function if supplied), randomly
       shuffle each group, and return the concatenation of the shuffled
       groups.

       """
       groups = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(iterable, key)]
       for group in groups:
           shuffle(group)
       return list(chain(*groups))
   ```